# 浮動小数点で表現できる10進数の桁数は？

Tags: 浮動小数点数

半精度浮動小数点数および単精度浮動小数点数では、
10進数では何桁まで表現できるのでしょうか。

表現したい数値は、10進数5桁程度（999.99）の数値なのですが、
半精度でよいのか単精度とする必要があるのか、
どのように判断したらよいのかがわかりません。

半精度の場合、仮数部が10bitであり、10bitで表現できる10進数は
最大1024となるため、半精度では10進数5桁を表現できない？
という考えは間違ているでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

半精度だと、いわゆるケチ表現のおかげで1bit増えて実質11bit分の精度がありますが、それでも2048までしか表現できないので、結論としては10進3桁程度ということになります。
(Wikipediaの[IEEE754 基本形式](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC%E5%BD%A2%E5%BC%8F)にある表の十進換算桁数を参照)

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。